# Flutter Push Notification via Laravel using Firebase

Tags: laravel, flutter, firebase

I've developed a mobile application using Flutter and Laravel. There are two types of user in my application: drivers and passengers. When users take an action, it is passed on to the API, which sends back a response. I'd like to implement notifications within my application. When a passenger makes a reservation on a driver's offer, a notification will be sent to the driver concerned (the reservation system works). The notification therefore needs to be created in the API before being sent to Firebase for display on the mobile device concerned (as it's in the API that I can access the token that identifies the driver's device). So that's my problem, I haven't really found a solution that allows me to send a notification from my Laravel API to Firebase so that it can be sent to the relevant mobile application.

I tried using the Laravel package kutia-software-company/larafirebase but I didn't understand much about it, the same as for the majority of the answers I found (which may solve the problem on a flutter web application but not on mobile). I'm just looking for a method, whatever it is, that allows me to trigger the sending of a notification from Laravel to a flutter mobile application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.